# How to query attached fiels from library in Lightning style?

Tags: lightning, soql, lightning-experience, files, libraries

I have the following query:

```
List<Document> attachments = [Select Id, Name, Type, Folder.Name, FolderId From Document WHERE Folder.Name = 'Team Attachments'];
```

In Lightning I have the same library `Team Attachments`.
[image]
How do I change the above query to retrieve all attachments from the `Team Attachments` library to make it work under Lightning Experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query will be same. You need to use @AuraEnabled method to return the records.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Document> getTeamAttachments(){
    List<Document> attachments = [Select Id, Name, Type, Folder.Name, FolderId 
                                         From Document 
                                         WHERE Folder.Name = 'Team Attachments'];
    return attachments;
}
```

You can iterate over returned list of attachments in lightning component javascript